# Is my mobile app free or paid in Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, mobile-application, google-play-console

I am trying to create my first (ever) mobile app in the Google Play Console. When creating the app, it asks if the app I am about to create is free or paid.

[image]

My app will be free to download and some content will be free as well. At the same time, there will be some premium content which will be available via in app purchases. I am now very confused about which one to select in the app creation process. Is my mobile app free or paid?

Hoping that people having more experience in the domain see my question...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your game should have a marking that will tell the user downloading the game if there are in-app purchases. The game in general will be free though.

Have a great day!